# Selenium cannot find element

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, find, element

Having some issues using Selenium web driver in Chrome.

My goal is to give the user ~15-30 seconds to log in on there own and then start doing automated testing.

The problem is after I click the login button and go to the next page, I am not able to find elements by xpath, id, etc.

```
public static void runTest() throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.url.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content-main\"]/div/div/form/div/p/input")).click();

    System.out.println("User has logged in and it has found element for Attachment Upload.");
    Thread.sleep(15000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"invoiceMenu\"]/a")).click();
}
```

I have also tried using explicit waits and have had no luck for example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));
```

The error I am usually getting back is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id="invoiceMenu"]/a (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Edit:

Was able to get some of the elements (angular ones) working with a few plugins for Chrome. Element Locator and ChroPath worked fantastic. Took some playing around with, but once I got one I was able to piece together the rest of them.

Comment: may element isn't visible or it can be inside a frame too. However the given URL isn't working on my network . is it publicly accessible? Next steps : share the relevant HTML.

Comment: After a little more research it seems the issue is the element I am trying to interact with is written in Angular. Was testing with some other elements on the page and it worked. Going to do a little research now to see how to deal with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you open the chrome console on your browser and try to interact with the element in question e.g. using:

```
document.getElementById('someId').click()
```

If you are able to click on the element like that, then you can use javascript executor in your code as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('someId').click();");
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I did figure out the element I am trying to access is written in Angular. I guessed that was causing issues and tested some other elements on the page that were not using Angular and it worked. Going to look into how I deal with Angular elements.